# How to access <div> element in HTML from a embedded .svg file

Tags: html, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have got an html page having couple of <div> elements in html and embedded svg:

```
<html>
...
<body>
  <object id='svgid' data='sample.svg'.../>
  <div id="errorMsgs" style="display:none; height:100%; width:100%; overflow:scroll;"/>
  <div id="warnings" style="display:none; height:100%; width:100%; overflow:scroll;"/>
</body>
...
</html>
```

Inside the sample.svg, I have got couple of java script functions; in case of any errors or warnings, these functions are supposed to hide the entire svg display and bring up the <div> element to visibility. But this is not happening in IE9. The DOM document available inside sample.svg seems to refer the SVG elements of sample.svg, not the html <div> elements. How can I access the <div> elements from the sample.svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object` element is a [nested browsing context](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#nested-browsing-context).  You should be able to access your elements with code along the lines of:

```
var errors = parent.document.getElementById(errorMsgs);
var warns = parent.document.getElementById(warnings);
```

[Here's a simple example of the concept](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/scripted.html).  I <strike>can't test it in IE9 right now, but i</strike>t works in Firefox and Chrome.  In IE9 it works, but there's a [weird bug](http://ffwd.typepad.com/blog/2011/07/svg-object-caching-trouble-for-ie9.html) which means the SVG takes several minutes to load.